# Example of outMessagePolicy option in WSPolicy class in WSO2 WSF/PHP

Tags: php, web-services, ws-security, wso2, wsh

i need some information on how to put data in this property. In docs there's no info, google is dumb about this. All i need is tiny little example how to initialize this:) My code looks like this:

```
$some_sec_array = array(); // here, give my anything
$policy = new WSPolicy(array("outMessagePolicy"=>$some_sec_array));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outMessagePolicy` accepts the same keys than the basic WSPolicy object, it's just a way to separate inbound and outbound policies. So you can use the keys defined in the [API documentation](http://wso2.org/project/wsf/php/2.1.0/docs/api.html):

```
sign
encrypt
algorithmSuite
layout
includeTimeStamp
protectionOrder
useUsernameToken
securityTokenReference
encryptSignature
binding
```